# Creating custom images on MEAN stack

Tags: html, image, node.js, canvas

I have been doing a lot of research on the web and haven't come up with a great solution going forward on what I am trying to accomplish.  Essentially the goal is to create something like shutterfly where the user picks a background image, some pictures, some text, some layouts and it will show it in the browser and have the image be downloadable of what they have created.

It seems like an extremely common use case but I can't seem to find a workflow that fits my requirements.  I have looked at the HTML5 canvas and that can work however it seems like the text is ugly and overall difficult to work with. Having multiple images/text blocks and have all of it be customizable to the user I can't seem to get to work properly.

Ideally I would be able to in the browser just use HTML to create the picture and then when the user selects everything, I would have the server side generate the image based upon the specifications.  However I can't seem to find a library for nodejs that fits this desire.

I am new to working with image manipulation so I am unsure on what the best approach would be.

Comment: Did a bit of research and in general, the support for image manipulation in NodeJS is kinda weak. I did find [this](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) which may be useful.

Comment: Canvas manipulation is pretty easy with node-canvas I've used it on a few sites to include http://retroships.com however this question is way too open ended.